# Folder level access control inside containers in ADLS

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-rbac

I can see storage service level and container level access control but Is it possible to assign folder level access control for users and service principals?

Comment: No, there isn't a folder level access control in ADLS. We can't assign it for users or service principals.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a folder level access control in ADLS. We can't assign it for users or service principals.

Azure Data Lake only suppurt: Service, Container, Object level access control.

[image]

HTH.